# Using Python selenium automation ChromeOptions to allow flash like we do for firefox using profile

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver, webautomation

I was looking for the option to enable flash and other internal plugin to be enabled using chrome option so that my web automation passes without any human operation.

For Firefox it is working as,

```
profile = webdriver.FirefoxProfile()
profile.set_preference('plugin.state.flash', 2)
```

but I want to do using chrome and all integrated plugin and flash should be enabled by  default. Need help regarding this.

Using python.

Comment: Your answer could be here - https://sqa.stackexchange.com/questions/30312/enable-flash-player-on-chrome-62-while-running-selenium-test

Comment: I had checked that earlier, I am looking for the way using python as I am new to both python and selenium.

Comment: @DebanjanB, No, it's not. I am looking for the flag which I can set using python.

Comment: @DhirajJha Do you mean you need the Pythonic version?

Comment: Yes @DebanjanB. I am looking for the pythonic version.

I got this but I am not sure how to do it by python.
ChromeOptions options = new ChromeOptions();
Map<String, Object> prefs = new HashMap<>();

// Enable Flash
prefs.put("profile.default_content_setting_values.plugins", 1);
prefs.put("profile.content_settings.plugin_whitelist.adobe-flash-player", 1);
prefs.put("profile.content_settings.exceptions.plugins.*,*.per_resource.adobe-flash-player", 1);
options.setExperimentalOption("prefs", prefs);
ChromeDriver driver = new ChromeDriver(options);

Comment: Thanks @demouser123 it worked for me.